# geocoder results within a jQuery $.each loop and callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, each, google-geocoder

I provide a HTML form which has multiple rows(up to 100). Every *row* holds a address field at least. On execution (by button) a function (*populateFormFieldsWithLocations*) iterates over every scope, calls google.gecoder and applying the results into the DOM (hidden inputs). After this, another function(*convertAndPasteJSON*) is executed to get the form values, serialize them, stringify the object to JSON syntax and paste that into a copy area.

As google.geocoder is a asynchron task (while *$.each* is not), i have to slow down the execution of the second function a bit currently with *setTimeout()*. Works(when setting a min delay amount of 500ms at least).

But this a weak and unsatisfying approach as the execution has no relation to each other which could causes problems in unkown technical environments. I am sure this should be handled with a **callback**. But i fail to implement this in this particular example, although i read and tried a lot (played with jquery deferred objects) - i still don't get it.

It would very kind, if someone has some short hints maybe how to do this...

**Code (Excerpt):**

```js
function populateFormFieldsWithLocations() {

  $.each($('.row'), function() {

    // context
    var scope = $(this);

    // get routeaddress value on each context row
    var address = $('textarea#routeaddress', scope).prop('value');

    ...

    // get geocoder coords and populate form fields 
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var coord = results[0].geometry.location;
          $('input#lat', scope).val(coord.lat());
          $('input#lng', scope).val(coord.lng());
        }
    });    
  });
}

function convertAndPasteJSON() {
  var o = $('.convert-to-json').toObject({mode: 'combine'});
  o = JSON.stringify(o, null, 2);
  $('.convert-to-json-result .result').val(o);
}

// on dom ready
$(function() {

  $('.convert-to-json button').on('click', function(e) {

    // execute collecting data
    populateFormFieldsWithLocations();

    // execute conversion to JSON with a delay
    setTimeout("convertAndPasteJSON()", 500);

  });

});
```

**HTML (Excerpt):**

```html
<form action="." method="post" class="convert-to-json">

  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="markers[0].lat" id="lat" />
    <input type="hidden" name="markers[0].lng" id="lng" />

    <div>                               
      <label for="routeaddress">routeaddress</label>
      <textarea name="markers[0].routeaddress" id="routeaddress"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- ... many more ".rows" ... -->

</form>
```

Comment: You should use promises.  (`$.Deferred()` and `$.when()`)

Comment: Thx. But that's the point. I have no concrete idea to apply this to the code above.